# Returning an unauthorized response in actix-web middleware in Rust

Tags: rust, middleware, actix-web

I have dove into the wonderful world of Rust and the Actix-Web the past few weeks and I am working on building various types of authentication through a piece of actix-web middleware. I have all of the auth logic completely figured out, but I cannot figure out how to return an unauthorized HTTP response from the middleware if a user fails an authentication check.

Here is how the Service trait is defined. Very standard from what I have seen.

```
impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for AuthMiddleware<S>
  where
      S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>
          + 'static,
      S::Future: 'static,
      B: 'static
  {
      type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
      type Error = Error;
      type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>>;
```

And here is the end of `call()` where I am attempting return a particular response based on if the variable `authenticate_fail` is true.

```
let svc = self.service.clone();
if authenticate_fail {
    return Box::pin(async move {     
        let res = req.into_response(
            HttpResponse::Unauthorized()
            .finish()
         );
         Ok(res)
    })
}
```

The issue I am having is that Rust yells at me because the **res** variable is `ServiceResponse<AnyBody>` when it needs to be `ServiceResponse<B>`.

Now I can see that the reason for the issue seems to lie with the fact that I am using Actix Web 4 in which the `into_response()` method will return a Response object but it will have the type `<AnyBody>` rather than `<B>`. I know that I could go to Actix 3.3.2 to fix the issue, but I am hoping somebody might be able to either explain what I am doing incorrectly here or show me whatever is considered the correct way in Actix 4 to return an unauthorized response from middleware.

I am still very new to Rust, so I am sure that there could be something here that I am not understanding fully.

Thanks!

Comment: Searching for the exact same issue...

Comment: @Deisss Have you figured anything out? Please let me know if you do.

Comment: I did, I simply remove the template "B" everywhere... Did the trick for me then it accepts to compile and works well again...

Comment: That worked. That you! @Deisss

Comment: @Deisss It helped! thank u.

Answer (score 2):

In actix 4.0 they introduce a new type called  `Either` to use it as Left or Right result based on your need.

For example `Left` could be the result of other middleware responses and `Right` could be the result of your middleware.

In the below code, I had to return UNAUTHORIZED  in case the JWT token is Invalid or return other middleware response

```
use pin_project::pin_project;
use std::{
    env,
    marker::PhantomData,
    pin::Pin,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};

use actix_utils::future::{ok, Either, Ready};
use actix_web::{
    body::{EitherBody, MessageBody},
    dev::{Service, ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse, Transform},
    http::{Method, StatusCode},
    Error, HttpResponse,
};
use futures::{ready, Future};
use jsonwebtoken::{decode, Algorithm, DecodingKey, Validation};

use crate::modules::user::models::Claims;
pub struct Authentication;

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for Authentication
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: MessageBody,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<EitherBody<B>>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = AuthenticationMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(AuthenticationMiddleware { service })
    }
}
pub struct AuthenticationMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
}

impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for AuthenticationMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: MessageBody,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<EitherBody<B>>;

    type Error = Error;

    type Future = Either<AuthenticationFuture<S, B>, Ready<Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>;

    fn poll_ready(&self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let mut authenticate_pass = false;

        if Method::OPTIONS == *req.method() {
            authenticate_pass = true;
        }

        let auth = req.headers().get("Authorization");
        if auth.is_some() {
            let _split: Vec<&str> = auth
                .unwrap()
                .to_str()
                .unwrap()
                .trim()
                .split("Bearer")
                .collect();
            let token = _split[1].trim();
            let secrt_key = env::var("SECRET_KEY").expect("SECRET_KEY in .env file is missing");
            let key = secrt_key.as_bytes();

            if decode::<Claims>(
                token,
                &DecodingKey::from_secret(key),
                &Validation::new(Algorithm::HS512),
            )
            .is_ok()
            {
                authenticate_pass = true;
            }
        }

        if authenticate_pass {
            Either::left(AuthenticationFuture {
                fut: self.service.call(req),
                _phantom: PhantomData,
            })
        } else {
            let res = HttpResponse::with_body(StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid JWT Token");
            Either::right(ok(req
                .into_response(res)
                .map_into_boxed_body()
                .map_into_right_body()))
        }
    }
}

#[pin_project]
pub struct AuthenticationFuture<S, B>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest>,
{
    #[pin]
    fut: S::Future,
    _phantom: PhantomData<B>,
}

impl<S, B> Future for AuthenticationFuture<S, B>
where
    B: MessageBody,
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
{
    type Output = Result<ServiceResponse<EitherBody<B>>, Error>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let res = match ready!(self.project().fut.poll(cx)) {
            Ok(res) => res,
            Err(err) => return Poll::Ready(Err(err.into())),
        };

        Poll::Ready(Ok(res.map_into_left_body()))
    }
}
```